# Check for duplicate Wordpress Post with Custom Meta Data on Publish

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

I have a site that uses a custom meta-box with the following fields using Meta-Box plugin. Code is as follows 
`

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title' => 'MLS ID',
        'pages' => array('property'),
        'fields' => array(

        array(
                  'name'  => 'MLS ID',
                  'id'    => "IntegratorPropertyID",
                  'desc'  => 'MLS: e.g. 240091025-217',
                  'type'  => 'text',
                ),
        array(
          'name'  => 'Test MLS',
          'id'    => "mlsTest",
          'desc'  => 'Test MLS for Duplicate',
          'type'  => 'button',
        ),
    ),
        'validation' => array(
                'rules' => array(
                    "IntegratorPropertyID" => array(
                'required' => true
            ),                
        ),
        'messages' => array(
                        "IntegratorPropertyID" => array(
                    'required'  => 'MLS is required',
                ),
            )
        )    
    );
```

Now what im looking for is to add an '`add_action( 'save_post', 'checkMLS' );`' function that checks all previous CPT property for MLS number to make sure it hasn't been input before. The code I used was:

```
    function checkMLS( $post_id ) {
            $slug = 'property';
            if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            return;
                }
                $mls2 = rwmb_meta('IntegratorPropertyID', 'type=text', $post_id);
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'property' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $this1 = get_the_ID();
            $mls1 = rwmb_meta('IntegratorPropertyID', 'type=text', $this1);
            if ( $mls2 == $mls1 ) {
                $my_post = array(
                    'ID'    => $post_id,
                    'IntegratorPropertyID' => 'DUPLICATE!'
                    );
                wp_update_post($my_post);
                return;
            }
            endwhile;
        }
add_action( 'save_post', 'checkMLS' );
```

That code is found in the functions.php and when I try to post the screen goes white. Debugging mode does not offer any help either. :/

I'm sure I'm making some programming Major mistake somewhere. Can someone point it out? or maybe point me in the right direction? or suggest something completely different?

Thanks 
Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Firstly, your white page with no indication of why, is probably either an 'out of memory' error, or a php 'max execution time' error. This stims from one major flaw in the way the `checkMLS()` function works. The flaw is that you are literally cycling through ALL `'property'` posts in your database. Depending on the size of your dataset, this can be a LOT, especially considering you are dealing with MLS lists.

**MY RECOMMENDATION:**

Figure out how the `rwmb_meta()` function is grabbing it's information. It is probably just a wrapper function for the `get_post_meta()` function, but maybe not. Assuming that it is, I propose doing the following, which I will explain the details of after as well as in the comments:

```js
// the save_post action runs after a post has been saved/created, and has two parameters
// param 1: the id of the post
// param 2: the post object
function checkMLS($post_id, $post) {
  // use the post object post_type to determine if this is a property or not.
  // it will be a lot more reliable
  if ($post->post_type != 'property') return;

  // meta_key should be equal to the 'meta_key' field in the wp_postmeta table, for the 
  // id you are trying to check against. your example used IntegratorPropertyID. 
  // again you may want to check rwmb_meta() function to figure out if there is a
  // 'prefix' or 'suffix' added to this. despite that, it is almost certainly going to 
  // be looking in the wp_postmeta table, so this should work nicely
  $meta_key = 'IntegratorPropertyID';

  // look up the current mls id for this post, which you just saved/created
  $mls_id = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, true);

  // lookup in the actual database table for any matching row, that has the same MLS id
  // that is not this post.
  global $wpdb;
  $q = $wpdb->prepare('select post_id from '.$wpdb->postmeta.' where meta_key = %s and meta_value = %s and post_id != %d limit 1', $meta_key, $mls_id, $post_id);
  $exists = $wpdb->get_var($q);

  // if it already exists, mark the value as a duplicate
  if ($exists) update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, 'DUPLICATE!');
}

// add your check function late in the actions, at priority 10000
add_action('save_post', 'checkMLS', 10000, 2);
```

From the top, we create a callback with two params, because the `save_post` action sends two, `$post_id` and `$post`. Since save_post runs **after** the post has been saved, you already have an object (`$post`) which has all the post info in it. We can then use that `$post` object to determine the type of the post, which is more reliable than looking at a `$_REQUEST` value, mainly because `$post` is pulled directly from the database and passed to you.

Now, as stated before I assume that `rwmb_meta()` is just a kinda wrapper function for `get_post_meta()`. It probably adds a prefix or suffix to the `$meta_key`, but a little research into the `rwmb_meta()` function should tell you how the `$meta_key` is changed when passing it to the `get_post_meta()` function, and you can modify `$meta_key` from there. With the correct `$meta_key`, we can now get the MLS id of the property you just saved.

With that MLS id, we need to do a direct lookup in the database, to determine if there is another property with that id already. While the way in your demo function does work on small sets of data, there is no way it would work on any appreciable amount of properties. Thus the direct approach is needed. Simply we craft some special SQL to look in the `wp_postmeta` table for any `post_id` that has an MLS id that is equal to the one entered for this property, that is not this property. If we find one match that is not this property, then it is a dupe. If it is a dupe, we need to mark it as a dupe.

Notice that this solution does not do any looping at all. There is no potential for it to loop over 10000 records to find a dup id. This is streamlined. It looks up the id directly in the db, to see if there are dups.

Hopefully this is helpful to you, and hopefully others find it helpful as well. My company does WordPress work, almost exclusively. Through our years of working with WordPress we have encountered problems from the super simple to the overly complex. This same problem, in different settings, has manifested with many of our clients. This solution is simple and to the point, though highly custom. It will however, work.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm :) Sorry i never replied